# visual studio how to share exe with someone without visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, share, clr, visual-studio-2019

I made a small game visual novel like on visual studio (It runs on console) I am using it as a CLR proyect.

I want to share this app with a friend who doesn't have visual studio or any programming tool, how can i do this ?

I tried only compilers but they say stuff like "pch.h" not found or "conio.h" not found.

Is there a way to show this to my friend ?

Comment: If you use Visual Studio-specific headers, libraries, and technologies, you can't easily move your code to a non-Visual Studio environment. You might as well be speaking a different language. Try to stick to Standard C++ where possible and write yourself an [abstraction layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer) that hides the differences between the different platforms where you cannot.

Comment: Did you create an "*.exe" file? That would be the way to share the result.

Comment: If you just want to show off the program, not be able to built it, on your friend's computer, compile the program and give your friend the exe file. They may have to install the appropriate .Net Framework and Visual C++ Redistributable library to run the program, though.

Comment: @supersuper what you want to share ? exec, librairies, project, ...?

Comment: @Yunnosch I did i shared the proyect file from repos in a rar, i told the to open it they should go to 
Debug->FantasyCrusadersCLR.exe
but then they reply with "tells me there's missing dll files"

Comment: @Landstalker I want to share the exec

Comment: Build and share a Release version of the executable. If there are still missing DLLs, download and install the the Visual C++ Redistributable for your version of Visual Studio from Microsoft and install it.

Answer (score 0):

You must generate a setup wich will automaticaly detect all your program `dependencies`.
I suggest you create `setup project` that can detect all these dependencies:

**1-** install `Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects` from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudioclient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)
**2-** Download the appropriate VC Redist [here](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-be/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)
**3-** Put your project in `release` mode
**4-** Add setup project to your `VS solution`

[image]

**5-** Add your program to the setup project

[image]

**6-** Choose primary output of your project

[image]

**7-** Add the downloaded `VC_redist.x86.exe` to setup

[image]

[image]

**8-** Go to project `custom action`
[image]

**9-** Add `VC_redist.x86.exe`

[image]
[image]

**10-** Build your setup project, Give the generated `msi` to your friend and have fun !
[image]